# Chamar Activity após login no Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-sdk

Sou novo no mundo *Android* e estou precisando de uma ajuda.
Não consigo fazer a chamada para uma nova *activity* após o *facebook* *login*.

O *login* está rodando corretamente e quando é realizado com sucesso, volta a mesma *activity* com o botão para *Logout*. Tentei fazer a chamada por `Intent`, mas não funcionou. Poderiam me ajudar, por favor.

Estou usando o *facebook sdk 4.0*

Segue abaixo o código do *main fragment*:

```java
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private TextView textView;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayMessage(profile);


        }


        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };

    public MainFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                displayMessage(newProfile);
            }
        };

        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Intent intent = new Intent();


    }

    private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
        if(profile != null){
            textView.setText(profile.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer o redirecionamento, você pode verificar se o usuário está *logado* e se o *token* deste mesmo usuário já expirou. Neste caso, ficaria desta forma abaixo. Veja:

```
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayMessage(profile);

    boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();

    if(isLoggedIn){
      // aqui dentro você deve chamar sua activity.
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seria isso?

```
   @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
        startActivity(getContext(), NovaActivity.class);
    }
```

Comment: Olá, Androiderson, já tentei desta forma e recebo um erro: Error:(40, 13) error: method startActivity in class Fragment cannot be applied to given types;
required: Intent
found: Context,Class<StationFragment>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Tem certeza de que seu `NovaActivity.class` é uma `Activity`e não um `Fragment`?

Comment: Agora arrumei para a activity principal, mas quando retorna ela fica com o botão de logout na tela...     o código ficou assim:                 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayMessage(profile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), StationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: e ao iniciar o app novamente ele cai na tela de logout e não para a activity principal

Comment: Toda vez que o usuário cair na tela de login, e ele já estiver logado, você tem que fazer o redirecionamento para a tela correta. Isso não é automático, você que tem que implementar.

Comment: Neste caso devo usar o lifecycle do próprio facebook sdk?

Comment: Não, o facebook só te informa se o usuário está ou não logado, o resto é contigo.